iOS 18 CoreBluetooth scanForPeripherals method with a defined CBUUID is not detecting iPhone peripherals advertising in the background state
The Issue
iOS 18 CoreBluetooth - scanForPeripherals method with a defined CBUUID is not detecting iPhone peripherals advertising in the background state.
Setup

iPhone A (peripheral) - Advertising a service with a specific CBUUID myServiceUUID
iPhone B (central) - Scanning using the method sCentralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [myServiceUUID])

Test Cases

iPhone B (with iOS 18) - detects iPhone A in the foreground state (app open in the foreground)
iPhone B (with iOS 18) - FAILS TO detect iPhone A in the background state (app in background; not terminated)
iPhone B (with iOS 17 and below) - detects iPhone A in both foreground and background states

FYI

iPhone A could be any version of iOS
Test Case 2 is the ISSUE!

